# Visual Studio 2012 - Debug when pages are not local

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET and trying to get the debug feature working so I can see the values from the variables in the code. I know that I have done it all wrong from the beginning so the debug is not working properly now. Here is what I did.

A while ago, I played around and built a number of ASP.NET pages, kind of manually creating the .ASPX page and then the code behind page .ASPX.VB directly from the web server.  Everything is working fine. I have my desktop computer connected to the Web server, and mapped the directory contains all the web pages (including both classic ASP and ASP.NET), where I just right-click on the web page file and edit directly.

Now, I am updating some ASP.NET pages, and want to learn how to perform debug, but getting many errors when I put the breakpoint and run Debug.  Example of errors like "AjaxControlToolKit.Dll not found". Note that the page is still working fine if I view it from the browser, so the AjaxControlToolKit is there.

Can you please suggest the correct way that I should do to retain all the ASP.NET pages and also make the Debug feature working correctly? I have no problem to migrate all web pages from the web server to my local drive (desktop) if that requires for the Debug to work properly.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If it is too complicated to correct the problem, please suggest a correct way if I have to redo all this over again?  Should I work all the .NET files locally in my desktop, and then upload it to the server?  Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly you've got an uphill battle ahead of you - it's probably not debugging because the `<assembly name>.pdb` files are not in the BIN folder of your website, or if they are they are out of date (compared with the source files) or point to the wrong location (of the source files).

IMHO I think you should create a fresh web project in VS and then recreate each page in VS and copy the appropriate code.  I think that would be quicker and less risky.  The road you're currently heading down will take you on a tour of debugging which would be useful, but not necessary at this point in your learning.

Typically most people develop locally in VS and then use the Publish function (in VS) to create a folder you can then upload (manually if need be) to the remote server.

Usually you want to avoid debugging on the production server unless there's a problem specific to it, which isn't present locally.

Comment: Thanks @Jim.  Really appreciated your response.  By any change, do you know any good tutorial links for create a fresh web project (either VB or C# is fine), debugging locally, and publishing function in VS?

Comment: You're welcome https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/create-the-project or see codeproject probably

Comment: Thank you for the link.  Any tips of develop locally in VS? Such as: do I need to store my project files same structure as the IIS web server, like C:\inetpub/wwwroot\MyASPXProjectName? If I have a form where user can upload the file on the Web Server D drive eventually, how can I test that locally if my desktop only has a C drive?

Comment: No you put your VS project where-ever, and you should store any parameters (like file paths) in your web.config, then you can edit paths etc in the web.config (or you're able to setup a debug and a release web.config in the project with appropriate settings).  Also look at Server.MapPath it's very useful for dealing with paths.